# How do I connect to a docker container running on a different host on a mac?

Tags: macos, docker, nat, kitematic

I have set up docker on my Mac using Kinematic.  I have a mysql container running.

So, the 'schematic', I believe, looks like this: (Mac1 (VirtualBox Docker Host (MySQL Container))).

Mac1 IP: 10.10.10.100
MySQL Container: 192.168.99.100 running on port 32500 (mapped to 3306)

I can access the MySQL server via 192.168.99.100:32500 from Mac1 without any issues.

Now, when I go to Mac2 on my network, I cannot access the MySQL container.

So, Mac2 IP: 10.10.10.200 cannot see 192.168.99.100:32500.  Mac2 gets a ping response, but not sure if it is getting all the way to the MySQL Container.

I'm thinking of installing a proxy on Mac1, but wanted to check first.

None of the questions posed here seemed to account for a Kinematic install on a Mac, and the ones referring to boot2docker didn't address the question either.

Any insights would be most welcome!  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the simplest way to expose a container port to your network, you could map a virtual box port onto the mac1 and access it from outside.

Comment: Given that I set this up using Kitematic, what would be a good way to do this?  Thanks for the suggestion!  Would love to make this work.

Comment: @AaCc sorry, I don't use kitematic and their documentation on the web is not that extensive. I guess you could simply open Virtual Box, guess the VM that is associated with docker/kinematic (chances are there won't be more than one), go to Settings -> Network -> First adapter, the one bound to NAT and map the ports there. If things worked out you will be able to access your mysql via localhost:<the port you've mapped it to>, and then with some luck - also access it from the outside via `<the host running kinematic>:<the port you've mapped it to>`